# NSLookup command in Windows 10 VM for Azure key Vault is throwing error for timeout 2 seconds

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

In one of the on-prem server that DNS lookup for Azure key Vault is timed out. It happens randomly to the request not every time. The default server and Address is never empty and has value.

I checked port outbound port 443 is opened. I tried to clear the cache also for DNS but then also it is same thing.

[image]

Please help and advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did repro and it is working for me. The missing part is you need to establish the private link connection to Key Vault using the Azure portal or Azure CLI and Select the private endpoint you wish to approve.

Please follow this document to create private link connection to key vault:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/private-link-service?tabs=portal

**Command**

```
nslookup <your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net
```

Output –

[image]